# Different row counts in SQL Server synonym tables

Tags: sql-server

We have a table synonym but getting different row counts when I query both tables.

Is there any reason for this? This is a UAT environment so potentially something was missed in the restore. In Production the row counts tally.

Does something need to be rebuilt or recompiled? I can't see any uncommitted transactions but I wonder if it could be that.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that someone added some rows in stage?

Comment: your synonym is named `dbo.crm_scm_transaction` and you are querying `dbo.scm_transaction`

Comment: Yes Xedni. Shows how much I know about synonyms. I've completely misunderstood them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Querying wrong object. Should be SELECT * FROM dbo.cms_scm_transaction